# Keep the delegate argument names when compiling C++/CLI for .Net

Tags: c#, c++-cli, ildasm

In C# I can get Visual Studio to keep the delegate's argument names.
For example if I have:

```
public delegate void Blah(object myArg);
public event Blah Foo;
```

Then when I add a method to the event, Visual Studio UI automatically keeps the names and creates the method:

```
void Form1_Foo(object myArg);
```

But, if I declare a delegate in C++/CLI:

```
public:
delegate void Blah(Object^ myArg);
event Blah^ Foo;
```

it doesn't keep the names and creates a method with nonsense names:

```
void Form1_Foo(object A_0)
```

How can I set meaningful names to the argument in C++/CLI ?

**EDIT (Added ildasm results):**

C++ CLI event:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance void 
        Invoke(object myArg) cil managed
{
} // end of method Blah::Invoke
```

C# event:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void  Invoke(object myArg) runtime managed
{
} // end of method Blah::Invoke
```

Comment: What's the difference in the MSIL? (use `ildasm` on both)

Comment: No repro.  You ought to document the VS version I guess.

Comment: My earlier comment still stands.  Plus, share the compile settings, particularly whether you are generating debug information.

Comment: @BenVoigt Added the ildasm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has no hint at the real problem and I could not get a repro.  But later realized what might be happening, the C++ compiler is different from other managed compilers, and MSIL, it doesn't require parameters to be named in declarations.  That panned out:

```
namespace CppClassLibrary {
    public ref class Example {
    public:
        delegate void Blah(int, int, int, int);
        event Blah^ Foo;
    };
}
```

Produces this auto-generated event handler in C#:

```
    void test_Foo(int A_0, int A_1, int A_2, int A_3) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Looks like a slamdunk explanation.  You simply forgot to name the parameters in the delegate declaration, the C++ compiler is forced to synthesize them in order to write correct MSIL.  Easy to fix of course.

Comment: yeap, problem was i had the names in the raise event, not in the delegate. Add an example of the solution in the answer